# Application of the binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I have following question I can't get fully behind.

Suppose we have $n$ black balls and each ball independently has a probability of $\frac{1}{n^\frac{1}{3}}$ to turn red. Show that with a probability of at least $1-\frac{1}{n}$, that the number of red balls is at the most $O(n^\frac{2}{3})$.

I tried making a random variable $X_b$ for each ball $b$ that is $1$, if it turned red, and $0$ else. For these, it holds that $Pr[X_b=1]=\frac{1}{n^\frac{1}{3}}$. Then, since we have independent binary random variables, we can define $X:=\sum_{b} X_b$ for the number of red balls, which then in turn is binomially distributed. But now I'm stuck on what to do. Is this even the right approach?

Comment: I tried applying the chernoff bound which would then look as follows:
Since we want to show $Pr[X\leq c*n^\frac{2}{3}] \leq 1-\frac{1}{n}$, we then can apply the chernoff bound which then gives us:
$Pr[X\leq (1-\delta)*\mu] \leq \frac{1}{e^{\frac{\delta^2}{2}*\mu}}$.
In our case, $\mu = n*p = n*n^\frac{1}{3}=n^\frac{2}{3}$.
But then I dont know what to do.

Comment: Another approach would be to then use markov bound, which then gives us:
$Pr[X\geq c*\mu]\leq \frac{1}{c}$, we would then have to set $c=n$ and apply counterprobability but that wouldn't make sense. So I'm stuck again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that   $X_b=1$, if ball $b$ turned up red, and $0$ else. Then $p=P[X_b=1]= n^{-1/3}\ $  and $X:=\sum_{b=1}^n  X_b$    is Bin$(n,p)$ distributed, with mean $\mu=np=n^{2/3}$.

The relevant Chernoff bound [1]  to apply is the upper bound:
$$P [X > (1+\delta)\mu] < \left(\frac{e^\delta}{(1+\delta)^{1+\delta}}\right)^\mu.$$
Applying this with $\delta=1$, say, gives
$$P[X>2n^{2/3}] <(e/4)^{n^{2/3}} =o(1/n) \,.$$

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Multiplicative_form_(relative_error)

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! Had a similar approach but used the lower bound. Still looking why $\frac{1}{e^{\frac{4}{3}*n^\frac{2}{3}}}$ is $O(\frac{1}{n})$ but that should be doable.